Filter Gremlin traversal for match a vertex seen earlier in the traversal
I'm unsure how to filter by equality to a vertex stored earlier in the traversal with "as" in gremlinJS. Here is a contrived example to show exactly what I mean. This query checks for users that a given user LIKES that are not currently IS_FRIENDS_WITH that user.
await g.V(userId).as('user').out("LIKES").where(__.out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')).hasId(userId)

I would like to write the above as the below, which does not work, as hasId does not receive a string. Note the change in hasId.
await g.V(userId).as('user').out("LIKES").where(__.out('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')).hasId(__.select('user'))

This comes up in various situations. In one example, I have a builder function for constructing a query from creating a bidirectional 'IS_FRIENDS_WITH' edge between two vertices. The current version creates this between two hard coded edges.
query = query
      .coalesce(
        __.outE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').where(__.inV().hasId(targetUserId)),
        __.addE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')
          .to(__.V(targetUserId))
          .property('createdAt', new Date().toISOString()),
      )
      .property('updatedAt', new Date().toISOString())
      .V(targetUserId)
      .coalesce(
        __.outE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').where(__.inV().hasId(sourceUserId)),
        __.addE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')
          .to(__.V(sourceUserId))
          .property('createdAt', new Date().toISOString()),
      )
      .property('updatedAt', new Date().toISOString());

    return query;

I would like to create a new version that creates the edge between a target edge and the current vertex being traversed, as written below, which again errors at the hasId(__.select('source')) step.
query = query
      .coalesce(
        __.outE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').where(__.inV().hasId(targetUserId)),
        __.addE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')
          .to(__.V(targetUserId))
          .property('createdAt', new Date().toISOString()),
      )
      .property('updatedAt', new Date().toISOString())
      .V(targetUserId)
      .coalesce(
        __.outE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH').where(__.inV().hasId(__.select('source'))),
        __.addE('IS_FRIENDS_WITH')
          .to(__.select('source'))
          .property('createdAt', new Date().toISOString()),
      )
      .property('updatedAt', new Date().toISOString());

    return query;

So, how can I check for equality to a vertex reference earlier with .as('identifier')?

It looks like .cyclicPath() may work, but it's more of a hack and could go wrong if cycles appear for other reasons (which, in general they shouldn't). I'm not fond of this because it's imprecise and doesn't express it's purpose directly in this usage.
